# circles drawn with mouse in wxPython not coinciding with mouse position

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to draw filled circles on a wx.Panel by clicking the mouse. The circles appear, but they do not coincide where the mouse is clicked. A given circle appears only the *next time* the mouse is clicked. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to correct this problem? Thanks.

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        noResize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.RESIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        super(Test,self).__init__(parent,style= noResize, title=title,size=(800,800))

        self.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,200))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('#faf0e6')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.panel,1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def OnLeftDown(self, e):
        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('BLUE', wx.SOLID))
        x, y = e.GetPosition()
        self.dc.DrawCircle(x,y,3)
        print x, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None,title='TEST')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Should self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self) be **self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)** ? And seems it works well with my try.

Comment: Just information at the moment: I observe the same problem as the OP with the code cut and pasted.  Each circle is drawn when the next location is clicked.   The mod suggested by Jerry_Y doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "this is not the way that you draw a custom control".

You need to draw the custom control using the EVT_PAINT event, and cause the EVT_PAINT event to happen at appropriate times (using Refresh() and Update()).

Your application will need to be restructured so that the location of each circle is saved on the OnLeftDown event, and all circles are redrawn on EVT_PAINT.

Read the "Common Mistakes" section [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Painting_your_custom_control)

Especially:

> Mistake: Draw something on a wxClientDC and expect it will stay there until you draw something else (wrong because your window manager may throw away your drawing at any time - e.g. if the window is minimized or hidden behind something else - and will expect you can draw it back later when receiving a paint event)

---

(The reason your circles are not appearing is because wx must have decided there was no reason to refresh the screen until the new DC was created.    This behaviour is window manager dependent, which would likely explain why Jerry_Y saw something different.   In my case, the circles stay there when the window is obscured briefly by another window, but they disappear when the window is minimised and re-opened.)